# I clicked run in the vs code,i am seeing something i don't understand

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

I created a program in C, then clicked run in VS Code, it was about to scan string from user. I typed the string and press enter, then I am seeing something I cannot able to understand.

[image]

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings. Fix them.

Comment: Pay attention to the colored squiggly lines in VS Code. Hover over them, try to understand the issues, and fix the issues.

Comment: Why don't you enter a description of the screenshot? What do we see in the screenshot? What do you want to show us?

Answer (score 3):

The program finished.  It did not finish as you expected but it ran to the end.  I would suggest two things.  Click on the tab that says "problems" it will tell you about some bugs in your code.  Step thru the code one line at a time instead of running the code with no breakpoints.

Comment: i cleared code problems program is running, stills showing the words.i attached a new screenshot.

Comment: I still see a tab that says "Problems (4)".  If you are talking about the words after "Done" that is just information about the process that was spawned to run the debugger.  You can ignore that.  Don't ignore the tab that says "Problems (4)"  -- Those ARE problems.

Comment: check my new screenshot on "enter image description"

Comment: Nice @Teddy -- looks like you are fixing a lot of the problems.  I think you are getting the hang of it!